# Get a single item from the query Firestore

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get a single document from the Firestore Firebase  using Golang. I know that it is easy if you have an id, you can write something like this:

```
database.Collection("profiles").Doc(userId).Get(ctx)
```

In my case I need to find a specific document using a `Where` condition, and this is where I get stuck. So far I was able to come up only with the following:

```
database.Collection("users").Where("name", "==", "Mark").Limit(1).Documents(ctx).GetAll()
```

And it is obviously not the best solution since I am looking only for one (basically the first) document which follows the condition and using `GetAll()` seems really weird. What would be the best approach?

Comment: It's more code, but you can call Next and Stop instead of GetAll.

Comment: @CeriseLimón could you give me an example, please? Because
database.Collection("users").Where("name", "==", "Mark").Limit(1).Documents(ctx).Next().Stop() gives me an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application can call [Next](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#DocumentIterator.Next) and [Stop](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#DocumentIterator.Stop) to get a single document:

```
func getOne(ctx context.Context, q firestore.Query) (*firestore.DocumentSnapshot, error) {
    it := q.Limit(1).Documents(ctx)
    defer it.Stop()
    snap, err := it.Next()
    if err == iterator.Done {
        err = fmt.Errorf("no matching documents")
    }
    return snap, err
}
```